Solution Checking: given positive $a,b,c,x,y,z$ with $a+x=b+y=c+z = S$, show that $ay+bz+cx<S^2$
This question is from an Olympiad training website (question 5). I am aware there are multiple solutions given in this post for the same problem.
However, my solution seems to be fairly simple, and from what I've seen , these types of problems do not typically resolve to such strategies. So I'm wondering if I've gone wrong somewhere:
My Proof:
By AM-GM we have
$$
ay+bz+cx = \sqrt{a^2y^2}+ \sqrt{b^2z^2}+\sqrt{c^2x^2}\leq \frac{a^2+y^2}{2}+\frac{b^2+z^2}{2}+\frac{c^2+x^2}{2} \tag{1}
$$
Equality occurs (i.e. the quantity $ay+bz+cx$ is maximized) when $a=y,b=z,c=x$. Then the given condition is
$$
y+x=z+y=x+z=S \implies x=y,z \implies S = 2x \tag{2}
$$
Finally,
$$
ay+bz+cx = 3x^2 <4x^2 =S^2 \tag{3}
$$
Have I messed up?

Your solution is wrong. Another user has made a similar mistake. You can find it here.
Please don't be under the illusion that equality always maximizes the product and minimizes the sum.
To understand this, recall a fundamental algebraic identity.
$$\color{red}{(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2=(a-b)^2+4ab=(a-b)^2+(2\sqrt{ab})^2\tag{1}}$$
$$\color{red}{4ab=(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2\tag{2}}$$
Equation $(1)$ or $(2)$ clearly illustrates the AM–GM inequality. They also show that the sum $(a+b)$ is minimized when $a=b$ for the given product $ab$ (constant), and the product $ab$ is maximized when $a=b$ for the given sum $a+b$ (constant). It is important to note that the sum must be constant (restricted) for the product's maximum value. In your case, you are taking $a=y,b=z,c=x$ for the maximum value of $ay+bz+cx$ even though $a+y, b+z,$ and $c+x$ or $a^2+y^2, b^2+z^2,$ and $c^2+x^2$ are not restricted to any values. So, this condition (equality) does not always optimize the given expression. I hope it clarifies.
I hope this helps you!

Let $S = 1$ without loss of generality. The maximum that you obtained is
$$\frac {1}{2} \cdot \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{2} \cdot \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{2} \cdot \frac {1}{2} = \frac {3}{4}.$$
However, try $\left( a, b, c \right) \to \left( 1, b, 0 \right)$:
$$1 \cdot \left( 1 - b \right) + b \cdot \left( 1 - 0 \right) + 0 \cdot \left( 1 - 1 \right) = 1 > \frac {3}{4}.$$
This gives the actual supremum of the expression.

There are at least 3 things wrong here :
(1) Equality occurs when target quantity is maximized : this is unproven here. In general , Equality could occur at minimum value. Equality could even occur at intermediate values. Otherwise , all general maximization Issues could be simply resolved by saying all variables are Equal.
(2) You have got Equality , yet you have target value $3x^2$ & maximum value $4x^2$ , which are not Equal.
(3) We have a large gap between $3x^2$ & $4x^2$. Bounds are not tight. Some Case might occur between the gap. Existence of that Case will nullify your Proof.
